# how can i remove the pictures one by one as they appear

Tags: javascript

this is what I expect my code to do:

1. first click on display button puts picture 1 on the screen.
2. second click on the same button puts picture 2 on the screen while picture
   1 is still on the screen.
3. third click on the same button puts picture 3 on the screen while picture 1 
   and picture 2 are still on the screen. (now all three pictures are on the 
   screen)
4. fourth click on the same button, removes picture 1 from the screen while 
   picture 2 and 3 are still on the screen.
5. fifth click on the same button, removes picture 2 from the screen while 
   picture 3 is still on the screen.
6. sixth click on the same button, removes picture 3 from the screen. (now all 
   three pictures are removed from the screen).

but unfortunately it doesn't work exactly as I want.
it can't remove pictures one bye one.(step 4 & 5 & 6 of above list doesn't happen)
please help me.
thanks in advance.

here is the code:

```
<html>

<style>
body {
  text-align: center;
}
img.images {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: none;
}
div#display {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="display">Display</div>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/400/200" class="images" id="image-1" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/500/200" class="images" id="image-2" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/600/200" class="images" id="image-3" />
</body>

<script>

(function() {
  var count = 0;
  document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
    var image;
    if (count < images.length) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 1;
      for (var x = 0; x < images.length; x++) {
        image = images[x];
        image.style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
   image = document.getElementById('image-' + count);
   image.style.display = 'block';
 }
})();
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use separate variables for the index to show and index to hide, to simplify your logic:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;
document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (displayCount < images.length) {
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    displayCount++;
  } else {
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    hideCount++;
    if (hideCount ===  images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
img.images {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: none;
}
div#display {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">Display</div>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/400/200" class="images" id="image-1" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/500/200" class="images" id="image-2" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/600/200" class="images" id="image-3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class for `visible` and a class for `hidden` elements and check how many are visible and how many are not to decide whether to shoe or hide the images,

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
var index = 0;

document.querySelector('#display').onclick = function() {

  if (document.querySelectorAll('.visible').length < images.length) { // if not all the images are visible
    images[index].classList.toggle('visible');
    index++;
  } else { // if not all the images are hidden
    images[index].classList.toggle('hidden');
    index++;
  }

  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.images {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

div#display {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

img {
  transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">Display</div>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/400/200" class="images" id="image-1" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/500/200" class="images" id="image-2" />
<img src="https://placekitten.com/600/200" class="images" id="image-3" />
```